# Countif statement in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I use countif statement in PostgreSQL?

```
max(COUNTIF(t1.A1:C10,t2.a1),COUNTIF(t1.A1:C10,t2.b1),COUNTIF(t1.A1:C10,t2.c1))
```

I have table1 which is more then a million rows

| a | b | c | M5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 27 | 31 |  |
| 3 | 7 | 27 |  |

and table2 more then 100 rows including different dates after column c

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | 16 |
| 30 | 40 | 50 |
| 60 | 70 | 80 |
| 16 | 18 | 37 |
| 5 | 12 | 16 |
| 8 | 31 | 28 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 7 | 9 | 31 |
| 2 | 7 | 21 |
| 20 | 16 | 27 |
| 8 | 12 | 17 |
| 2 | 8 | 14 |
| 3 | 14 | 15 |

The outcome should be something like this

| a | b | c | M5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 27 | 31 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | 27 | 2 |

Tried the below query but the outcome is not correct

```
UPDATE table1 SET m5 = greatest(
  case When a in(select unnest(array[a,b,c]) from (select * from table2 order by date DESC limit 10) foo) then 1 else 0 END,
  case When b in(select unnest(array[a,b,c]) from (select * from table2 order by date DESC limit 10) foo) then 1 else 0 END,
  case When c in(select unnest(array[a,b,c]) from (select * from table2 order by date DESC limit 10) foo) then 1 else 0 END)
```

Comment: Use FILTER: COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE ???)

Comment: Appreciate if you could provide full query please

Comment: Check the manual, always good to learn something: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are fixed and predictable, I think you could put all possible table values into a single column and then do counts for each occurrence:

```
with exploded as (
  select a from table2
  union all
  select b from table2
  union all
  select c from table2
)
select a, count (*) as count
from exploded e
group by a
```

So for example, the value 7 occurs twice (which would be reflected in this output).

From there, you can just do the updates from the CTE:

```
with exploded as (
  select a from table2
  union all
  select b from table2
  union all
  select c from table2
),
counted as (
  select a, count (*) as count
  from exploded e
  group by a
)
update table1 t
  set m5 = greatest (ca.count, cb.count, cc.count)
from
  counted ca,
  counted cb,
  counted cc
where
  t.a = ca.a and
  t.b = cb.a and
  t.c = cc.a
```

The only issue I see is if one of the values does not come up (the inner join fails), but in your example that doesn't seem to happen.

If it is possible, I would think that could be resolved with one more CTE to fill in missing values from table1 in the set of possible occurrences.